# Weird Fatal Exception in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, exception, fatal-error

im pretty new in the android world and i got a confusing bug which i cant handle.

I have the following ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this Activity:

```
package com.study.semesterplaner.vorlesungszeit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.study.constants.IntentConstants;
import com.study.droid.R;
import common.vorlesung.Vorlesung;
import common.vorlesung.VorlesungszeitHaeufigkeit;
import common.vorlesung.vorlesungszeit.Vorlesungszeit;

public class VorlesungszeitListActivity extends Activity{

    private ListView _listView;
    private ArrayList<Vorlesungszeit> _vorlesungszeiten;
    private VorlesungszeitListAdapter _listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_with_add_button);

        Vorlesung selectedVorlesung = (Vorlesung) getIntent().getExtras().get(IntentConstants.INTENT_VORLESUNG_DETAILS);
        _vorlesungszeiten = selectedVorlesung.getVorlesungsZeiten();

        _listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        _listAdapter = new VorlesungszeitListAdapter();
        _listView.setAdapter(_listAdapter);
    }

    private class VorlesungszeitListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _vorlesungszeiten.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return _vorlesungszeiten.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_three_textviews, null);
            TextView top = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_three_textview_ONE);
            TextView mid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_three_textview_TWO);
            TextView bottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_three_textview_THREE);

            Vorlesungszeit vZeit = _vorlesungszeiten.get(position);

            top.setText(vZeit.getTag() + ", " + vZeit.getVorlesungsbeginn() + " - " + vZeit.getVorlesungsende() + " Uhr");
            mid.setText("Raum: " + vZeit.getRaum());
            bottom.setText(VorlesungszeitHaeufigkeit.getHauefigkeitText(vZeit.getHaeufigkeit()));

            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

If i try to start this Activity i get this weird Exception:

```
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1136)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1267)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1128)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:915)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-17 21:48:38.867: E/AndroidRuntime(8864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dont know what is wrong. I tried to look for the troubleshooting code with the debugger, but the programm even dont access the onCreate Methode of the Activity ...

Comment: Can you post `row_three_textviews.xml`? And what version of Android you are using?

Answer (score 0):

import of `com.study.droid.R` seems suspect to me

Comment: you'd have to go out of your way for it to work that way. if your R class is generated from your res directory and everything it contains, it will have the same path as your code, and you won't have to import it. I could be wrong, but it just occurred to me, could be the problem.

Comment: I dont know if i understand you right. But the R class have not the same path as my code. I mean R is in the gen-folder and the code in the src-folder. If i delete the import, i get an compile-error, that i have to import the R-class.

Comment: do you know why your R is not in the same path as your code? that just does not seem ordinary to me. I just suspect that the errors may come from this mismatch.

Comment: isnt it normal to have two seperate folders, one with the R-class and one with the src code. All Android Projects i saw before had have the same scheme.

Comment: under your project folder you'll have a src folder and a res folder. in your gen folder, you'll have R.java, and in my experience, the package name in that file should be the same as the rest of your application. and I'm not saying for sure this is the problem; it just seems odd to me, and that's why I mention it.